# How to return several ID from an ASP.NET MVC view via a GET request

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a view in an ASP.NET MVC application with a table of data fetched from a database. Each row contains a checkbox.

```
for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
{
                <tr>
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].ID)
                    <td>
                        @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m[i].Selected)
                        
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(m => m[i].CN)
                        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].CN)
                    </td>
               </tr>
}
```

When I select several checkboxes by clicking the button, I need to send selected checkbox rows (or only selected rows IDs) to another controller as get request. How to do that. I found an solution to use java script on the page, but may be available ease method.

Comment: All that has been posted is a program description, but that doesn't tell us what _problem_ you're having. What have you tried, and what troubles did you encounter? Please [edit] your post to include a [valid question](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) that we can answer. Reminder: make sure you know what is [on-topic](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic); asking us to write the program for you, suggestions, and external links are off-topic.

Comment: I don't know how can I pass multiple IDs to another controller as get request. I found an solution to use java script which select checked checkbox, create url string and send it to controller, but may be exist more ease way to do that.
Script like that
$("#btnCancel").click(function () {
var url = "/ServiceAccounts/SubmitSelected?IDs=";
$("#Table1 input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function () {
 var row = $(this).closest("tr")[0];
 url += row.cells[1].innerHTML;
 url += ",";
 });
 location.href = url;
 });